# MonthlyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged event handler not setting property when a date is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

so I have two variables

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime selected;
```

and an event handler that should change the "selected" variable to the day selected on the calendar. time is a text box where a user can insert the time as well.

```
private void MonthlyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    selected = Calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
    selected = DateTime.Parse(time.Text);
}
```

How can I set the time portion of the selected variable? I know that since DateTime is immutable it can not be changed as easy as I would wish. currently the Parse call resets the selected varriable back to the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exactly change the time but you can try using timespan to add the time to the date

```
DateTime selected;
selected = Calendar.SelectedDate.Value;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(09, 15, 0);
selected = selected.Date + ts;
```

This would make it the same date but 9.15am

Comment: thats what Iv read is there anyway to use time span while parsing the textbox?

Comment: Should work in your method. Although, what is `time.Text`?

Comment: time is a textbox that contains a user inputted time such as 11:30 PM i have been using             date1 = DateTime.Parse(time.Text);
to set the time in my other variable.

Comment: Try using `TimeSpan.TryParse` and also give `DateTime.TryParse` a go rather than just parse

Comment: Try replacing the timespan line with this in my code above (put it in your method) `TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Parse("11:30 PM").TimeOfDay;`

Comment: that makes sense it also works for parsing time.Text thank you